# Pycharm pytest environmental variable in configuration tab is getting reset always

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, pycharm, pytest

For pytest module in Pycharm IDE, to print attributes or execute methods interactively in Debugger console, I learnt that I have to set "*-s*" for Additional Arguments under Edit Configurations tab. However, I was not able to default this *"-s"* flag to be applicable for all the test cases. I had to set *"-s"* flag for each test case individually whenever I run.

Later I learnt that I could use **JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING=-s** Environmental variable. However this Environmental variable is getting reset/cleared after a restart. Is there any way wherein I could preserve this setting forever?

Comment: Consider updating template in `Edit Configurations - Templates - ...`

Comment: I was not able to see Templates option under Run/Debug Configurations

Comment: Also it could be found in `Run (in the same bar as File, Edit, View, ...) - Edit Configurations - ...`